# Encoding spaces in s3.getSignedUrl() parameter

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

I am getting a "SignatureDoesNotMatch" 403 error from AWS from pre-signed urls for items in S3 when there is a space in the key name.  Of course spaces in key names are a bad idea.

When requesting the getSignedUrl, I've tried replacing the space with a plus sign, I've tried replacing spaces with %20, I tried various encoding schemes all to no avail.

```
key = "SOMEBUCKET/my file with a space.jpg";
key = key.replace(/ /g,"%20");
params.Key = key
s3Client.getSignedUrl('getObject', params, function(err, url) { }
```

What i get back is an error doc:

```
<Code>SignatureDoesNotMatch</Code>
<Message>
The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you 
provided. Check your key and signing method.
</Message>...
```

How to encode this so i can use S3.getSignedUrl() with spaces in key?  Thanks StackOverflow world for your help.

Comment: S3 does some bizarre things related to spaces in the key, but the SDK should have the sense to handle it correctly.  Can you pass the key with no escaping at all, and show us the complete error message from S3?

Comment: If I pass the non-encoded key in the params.key object, then the spaces in the key get urlEncoded automatically to %20.   The error message occurs for various encodings. Examples:
<StringToSign>
GET 1495488453 /petedampreview/broken-filez/image+with+a+space.jpg</StringToSign>

Comment: So, whether I use a %20, a plus or %2b for a url-encoded plus, the s3.getSignedUrl method does not return a working Url.

Comment: Did you find the solution? @PeteFriedman

Comment: Did you find the solution? @PeteFriedman